# "Home-Assistant" & "Google Home Assistant" Interaction

Tags: dialogflow-es, home-assistant

I'll explain my problem:

I have created an Intent Dialogflow that runs on the Home-Assistant software installed on a Raspberry.

I have to control with my voice a coffee machine and I used Dialogflow because I really want to have a conversation (so interaction) with Google Assistant... for example:

```
I: Hey Google, make the coffee
Google: espresso or american coffee?
I: espresso
Google: Intensity level from one to three?
I: three
Google: Water level from one to three?
I: three
Google: Okay, I'm making your coffee with ... <vocally collected parameters>
```

But the following message has appeared a few days ago on the console:

"This Conversational Actions will be removed on June 13, 2023..." So...

1. how can I do this interaction if I can't use Dialogflow?
2. What should I do to avoid losing everything my work and being able to continue using my application and the voice interaction of the three components I am using:
   A) Dialogflow
   B) Google
   C) Home-assistant?

Thanks

EDIT:
I refer to this:
[Google Actions Console](https://i.stack.imgur.com/neYCD.jpg)

Answer (score 0):

Dialogflow is not being removed.

If you are just using Dialogflow with its API (and I don't know Home Assistant, but it sounds like that is what it is doing), then there will be no change.

This message on the integrations page on Dialogflow is because the Google Assistant integration is enabled by default, but will be removed on 13 Jun 2023. [image]

Comment: Hi @Prisoner! Thanks for the reply. Sorry but I did not understand your message well ... (consider that I have been using these integrations for a short time and I am 'self-taught')


Please, could you be more clear?
thanks